# Two columns with separate scrollbars in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

How would I go about creating a two-column layout with separate scrollbars using Bootstrap 3? I know there are similar questions here, but they are all outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `overflow-y: scroll;` for vertical scroll bar:

### Bootply - [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/p31Jtk0LOC)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6 mydiv"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mydiv"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mydiv {
  height:300px;
  background: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**[EDITED]**

With a content `div` vertical scroll - **[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/k3zD1AM2cF)**